# Methods not firing immediately on change event

Tags: jquery, ember.js, onchange

The code below two issues.

1. When the user enters in the value 'coupon10' it removes the class 'disabled' and **should** unbind the click event which prevents the default behaviour, but it doesn't.
2. The user has to enter a random string into the field, delete it, then enter 'coupon10' to enable the button. So the change event works, but only after entering an incorrect string. I need it to work first time.

Might I add that I am using Ember 1.4 (not by choice)

### jQuery

```
  $(document).on('blur', 'input[name="coupon_code"]', function(){

    var form = $(this).closest('form');

    var couponBtn = form.find('input[name="apply_coupon"]');
    var couponCode = form.find('input[name="coupon_code"]');

    $(couponBtn).on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('timmy2')
    });

    $(couponCode).change(function(){
      if($(couponCode).val() == 'coupon10') {    
          $(couponBtn).removeClass('disabled');
          $(couponBtn).unbind('click'); 
          console.log('winning');                
      } else if ($(couponCode).val() != 'coupon10') { 
          console.log('hello');
      }       
    });   

  });
```

### HTML

```
<form name="ApplyCouponForm" method="post" action="/apply_coupon_check">
    <div class="form-row">

    </div>

    <input id="account_id" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="hidden" name="account_id" value="11">

    <div class="form-row with-border">
      <div class="field w100">
        <label for="coupon_code">If your employer has introduced you to Social CareLine, enter below the coupon code </label>
        <input id="ember767" class="ember-view ember-text-field" type="text" name="coupon_code" required="required">
      </div>
 <input class="apply-coupon disabled button submit-button no-margin-top" type="submit" value="Apply Coupon" name="apply_coupon">   </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="form-row">
       </div></form>
```

### CSS

```
.disabled {
  background: #dfdfdf!important;
  cursor: default!important;
  color: red;
}

.right-column .form-row {
  width: 518px; padding: 0px 0px; clear: both;
}

.submit-button {margin-top: 15px;}

.button.submit-button {
  padding: 8px 12px 8px 32px;
  background: #57d78d url("../images/submit-checkmark.png") no-repeat 10px center;
}

.right-column .main-submenu li.apply-coupon {
  background-image: url("../images/submenu-document.png");
}
```

Comment: Where is the `form`? Why are you binding `click event` and `change event` inside `blur` event?

Comment: As if I just used '$(function(){}' it wouldn't run. Not entirely sure. The version I am using is quite old

Comment: Could you please post relating `CSS` too??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao CSS has been included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your Issues**

---

- When the user enters in the value 'coupon10' it removes the class 'disabled' and should unbind the click event which prevents the default behaviour, but it doesn't.

> **Cause -** This was because your event of `change` on the `input` has been binded within `blur` of the same, which actually did not `bind`
>   unless and until it got `focus` and then blurred i.e. `lost focus`. However I am not sure as to why it *`should unbind the click event which prevents the default behavior`* because, if you have `disabled` it with adding attribute `disabled` to the `button`, it will not be clickable until you enable it. Have added the same in **`DEMO`** given below. Also `e.preventDefault()` for a `button` inside its `click event` will do the same, So IMHO no need to `unbind` `click event`.

- The user has to enter a random string into the field, delete it, then
  enter 'coupon10' to enable the button. So the change event works, but
  only after entering an incorrect string. I need it to work first
  time.

> **Cause -** As I said above, the behavior is because of the improper binding of elements `event`.

**Solution**

---

`disabled` attribute to `input element`

```
<input class="apply-coupon disabled button submit-button no-margin-top" 
type="submit" value="Apply Coupon" disabled name="apply_coupon"/>
                                   ^^^^^This here
```

Move the `events` out of the `blur event`.

```
$('input[name="coupon_code"]').on('input', function() {
    var ctrl=$(this);//$(this) refers to current clicked button
    var couponBtn=ctrl.closest('form').find('input[name="apply_coupon"]');
    //get its respective couponBtn

    if (ctrl.val() == 'coupon10') {
        $(couponBtn).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled',false);
        //remove button disabled attribute
        $(couponBtn).removeClass('disabled');
        $(couponBtn).unbind('click');//Not sure whether you need this now
        console.log('winning');
    } else if (ctrl.val() != 'coupon10') {
        console.log('hello');
        $(couponBtn).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled',true);
        //add button disabled attribute
    }
})

$('input[name="apply_coupon"]').on('click', function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('timmy2')
})
```

## [`FIDDLE DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2q88v0ck/)

**UPDATE**

---

After reading you first comment, I feel this is typical `event delegation` issue, wherein, `elements` to the `DOM` will be added after `DOM ready` i.e. dynamically, but the `events` will not be attached to them. So you need to attach the `events` either to the `element` which is present during `DOM ready` and where these `elements` will be appended, or directly to the `document` as you did with your `blur event`. Take below code in that case.

```
$(document).on('input','input[name="coupon_code"]', function() {
    var ctrl=$(this);//$(this) refers to current clicked button
    var couponBtn=ctrl.closest('form').find('input[name="apply_coupon"]');
    //get its respective couponBtn

    if (ctrl.val() == 'coupon10') {
        $(couponBtn).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled',false);
        //remove button disabled attribute
        $(couponBtn).removeClass('disabled');
        $(couponBtn).unbind('click');//Not sure whether you need this now
        console.log('winning');
    } else if (ctrl.val() != 'coupon10') {
        console.log('hello');
        $(couponBtn).addClass('disabled').attr('disabled',true);
        //add button disabled attribute
    }
})

$(document).on('click','input[name="apply_coupon"]', function() {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('timmy2')
})
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining in detail. Not sure why but I need to have the code within an event. I tried taking it out of the event and the script doesn't read it. What other event could I have in place of the 'blur' event?

Comment: Have included your code within the `blur` event and it works perfectly. I know it isn't ideal but it works. Thank you for time and help

Comment: I can relate it now, hope you are missing `event delegation` here.. Will edit my answer.. Do not simply compromise with functionality to make it work anyhow.. Check the updated answer..

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)